# What is a 'truncation'?

Tags: terminology

I've heard of many truncations in homotopy type theory, like propositional truncation, homotopy n-truncation, etc., and I think I understand these specific concepts.

People also talk about 'double-negation truncation', which talks about the 'double-negation' version of a certain type.

I'm wondering if there is a general definition or folklore notion called 'truncation'? Is it a special kind of modality or something?

Comment: A search for "double negation truncation" turns up nothing. Can you point to where this phrase is used?

Comment: I'm just guessing but I suppose you could call the double negation translation a "truncation" because you are losing the constructive information

Comment: @Trebor in our private conversations. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, truncations are a form of modalities, as explained in [Section 7.7 of the HoTT book](https://books.google.si/books?id=LkDUKMv3yp0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA245).

Comment: Thanks very much!